# Center CardView item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, alignment, android-recyclerview

> I am displaying a list of Products in RecyclerView where my

**item_row.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/tv_subject"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I have applied two properties to CardView to make it center but still my item View is left aligned

```
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

**main_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:text="Hello World"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I also added `android:layout_gravity="center"` to RecyclerView but still it's item Rows are left align..

How to align **CardView**(250dp width) in Center of RecyclerView ?
what am i missing.

my design of CardView in Preview Window..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNFNG.png)

**Edit - > Solution Found**

when I give `250dp widhth` to SwipeRefresh and set it's `layout_gravity="center"` then it center the View. **But why other solutions not working**??

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Try CardView width match parent...

Comment: Definetly it would work but I have to show cardView in small size @ParthLotia

Comment: Then Declare one main Linearlayout give width match parent , inside that Linearlayout declare CardView...